# Invalid Digital Order MIGS Payment Gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway

I use MasterCard Internet Gateway Service (MIGS) - Hosted Server (3-Party Payments) [http://www.appmerce.com/migs-vpc-mastercard-internet-gateway-service-magento.html#.VkWD9b_CeiE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq2F4.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq2F4.png): http://www.appmerce.com/migs-vpc-mastercard-internet-gateway-service-magento.html#.VkWD9b_CeiE  module for payment.i configure all detail but after redirecting it to api.it gives Invalid Digital Order  MIGS Payment Gateway  error.
here is screenshot [image]

i don't know what is issue  .i googled about this but not success.

Comment: The support from Appmerce is very, very bad. Don't use their extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have faced the same issue the problem is solved by removing the extra field value i was sending.

`<input type="hidden" maxlength="15" value="SINGLE" name="vpc_TxSourceSubType">`

after changing it's value to null  solved my problem

`<input type="hidden" maxlength="15" value="" name="vpc_TxSourceSubType">`

i hope it will help other too.

in your can case i see your `merchant account` detail is not correct or you are missing the `secret hash`

make sure you must have these field

```
<input type="hidden" maxlength="250" value="https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay" size="63" name="virtualPaymentClientURL">
<input type="hidden" value="test" name="Title">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="8" size="20" value="1" name="vpc_Version">
<input type="text" maxlength="8" size="20" value="aces_code" name="vpc_AccessCode">
<input type="text" maxlength="16" size="20" value="your" name="vpc_Merchant">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="16" size="20" value="pay" name="vpc_Command">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="40" size="20" value="1467269875" name="vpc_MerchTxnRef">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="34" size="20" value="this is product-10" name="vpc_OrderInfo">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="10" size="20" value="70" name="vpc_Amount">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="5" size="20" value="en" name="vpc_Locale">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="250" value="return_url" size="63" name="vpc_ReturnURL">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="15" name="vpc_TicketNo">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="15" value="" name="vpc_TxSourceSubType">
```

Comment: thank you,i couldn't solve  that.i had to get support them.i think this must help others to solve that kind of issue

Comment: I didn't have the `vpc_TxSourceSubType`. Even I added, the status is still HTTP Status 400

Comment: @Raptor these are not necessary the problem with you access code..

Comment: @QaisarSatti can you please have a look on this question please ?  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133684/http-status-400-followed-by-invalid-digital-order-during-checkout-with-migs

Comment: I tried your guide but still not working

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to make sure `vpc_MerchTxnRef` has a unique value for each request. If I sent any duplicate value then the mentioned error comes otherwise it works well.